# ¿Migrar un archivo .sql a MongoDB?

Tags: sql, mongodb

Quiero importar una base de datos de un archivo `.sql` a MongoDB, el problema es que pesa 1.7GB. Estuve investigando y encontre que puedo importar a mongodb una base de datos como archivo `.json`, pero las paginas para convertir a `.json` no soportan el archivo.

Existe alguna forma de poder importar la BD o de poder convertir mi archivo `.sql`.

Comment: eso no va a ser tan simple como lo planteas, niquisiera manejan la misma sintáxis investiga un poco mas como funciona Mongodb

Comment: Podrias exportar las tablas de tu BD de SQL a un CSV, luego convertir estos archivos CSV a JSON, y finalmente insertar los JSONs a Mongo. (Nota: esto solo insertaria la data, pero cualquier propiedad que describa a la tabla se perderia).

Comment: Gracias @cavpollo . Encontre la forma de hacerlo automatico con un PDI lo deje en la respuesta.

Comment: @AlfredoPaz tenias razon no fue tan facil, deje en la respuesta como lo logre. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Un comentario adicional, en realidad MongoDB no se maneja tan bien con relaciones como las bases de datos relacionales que fueron creadas para ese fin.
Realizar una migración correcta y prolija implicaría rediseñar la estructura de las tablas, y utilizar documentos embebidos en MongoDB, pero claro no es un trabajo ni rápido ni fácil. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Pude importar la Base de Datos de MySQL a MongoDB, utilizando:
- Robo 3T
- Pentaho Data Integration
- MySQL Workbench

Estoy utilizando Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

1. Robo 3T

   - Descargar de: http://www.veriapt.com/presentations/mde
   - Extraer y correr /robomongo/bin/robo3t
   - Crear una nueva conexion a mongodb(MongoDB ya debe estar corriendo por defecto en localhost:27017)
2. Pentaho Data Integration

   - Descargar y extraer: https://community.hitachivantara.com/docs/DOC-1009855-data-integration-kettle
   - Esta guia es imprescindible para que funcione Pentaho: http://www.veriapt.com/presentations/mde
     (En Install Pentaho Kettle 4.3.0 paso numero 3, agregar: cat ~/.bashrc)
   - Al extraer el archivo muestra una carpeta data-integration.
   - Descargar archivo jar para conectar MySQL: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.23﻿
   - Colocar el archivo .jar en /data-integration/lib (Esto nos ayuda a poder conectar mysql a Pentaho.
   - En la terminal escribir:

   /data-integration/spoon.sh

Automaticamente inicia el programa Spoon.

3. Importar de MySQL el archivo .sql
   Abrir workbench y usuario
   Crear un nuevo schema para la base de datos.
   Ir a: File > Open Sql script > seleccionar mibasededatos.sql
   Seleccionar el schema creado previamente y ejecutar.
4. Crear conexion en Spoon a Mysql
   -Ir al programa Spoon > View

   - Click derecho en Database connections.
   - Seleccionar 
     Connection type: MySQL
     Access: Native (JDBC)
     Connection name: mi conexion
     Host: localhost
     Database name: /*Nombre de la BD de Mysql*/
     Username and password: /*credenciales de Mysql*/
   - Seleccionar el boton test para ver si la Base de Datos se ha conectado.
   - En la pestana de Design > Input
   - Seleccionar la manera que se quiere importar la informacion y arrastrar a el panel derecho.
   - Doble click en input para ingresar la consulta de data que se desea.
   - En la misma pestana ir a Big Data > MongoDB Output y arrastrar a el panel.
   - Mapear el input a MongoDB.
   - En MongoDB Output seleccionar Output options > seleccionar la Base de datos de MongoDB y Collection.
   - Seleccionar Run, guardar la transferencia y ejecutar.

Y la data se almacena exitosamente en MongoDB.